# readonly text field coming required

Tags: java

I am facing a problem that I have a text field and if that field is editable I have to make it required. But if the field is read-only (as sometimes the field is read-only based on some conditions ) then also that field is coming required. So I'm not able to get over it .

Although if I check the code in browser it's working fine, giving optional for that field. I am using the below code:

```
//defining the values

Boolean isReadonlyWhenHostnameBlank = Boolean.FALSE;
Boolean isNotRequiredWhenHostNameBlank = Boolean.TRUE;

//changing the variable based on some condition i.e. if a particular field having null value.
if (value == null || Arrays.toString(value).equals("[]")) {
  isReadonlyWhenHostnameBlank = Boolean.TRUE;

  isNotRequiredWhenHostNameBlank = Boolean.FALSE;
}

//making it readonly and required based on the condition
if (controlId != null &&
    (controlId.contains("circuit_servers_portassignment") ||
      controlId.contains("circuit_servers_globalip")||
      controlId.contains("circuit_wf_servers_portassignment")||
      controlId.contains("circuit_wf_servers_globalip")||
      controlId.contains("circuit_staticnat_globalIP"))) {

  control.setReadOnly(isReadonlyWhenHostnameBlank);

  control.setRequired(isNotRequiredWhenHostNameBlank);

  System.out.println("isNotRequiredWhenHostNameBlank "+isNotRequiredWhenHostNameBlank);

  System.out.println("isReadonlyWhenHostnameBlank "+isReadonlyWhenHostnameBlank);
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.toString(value).equals("[]")` causes eye-bleeding for me. Please, fix it with `value.length == 0`

Comment: i am making the field optional if it is read only .. in backend code in browswr it's showing optional for that field ... but still it shows an error that the field is required ...

Comment: well i can do that ... but that won't solve the issue .

Comment: Also, there's no need to use non-primitive wrapper for `boolean`. All the `Boolean` may be moved with `boolean` (`Boolean.FALSE` -> `false` ; `Boolean.TRUE` -> `true`). Even if you really want to use object-wrapper for `boolean`, you still may use `false` (for example) instead of `Boolean.FALSE` as these values are [auto-boxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). I'm writing this just to make your code clearer and easier to read for other people, please, fix the code after that.

Comment: ok ..thanx..i"ll do that ...but for now my head is got stuck in that issue :)

Comment: thanks everyone.. got this fixed ... changed this in jsp file instead of this java file ...working fine

Comment: @avi feel free to answer your question yourself to indicate to all that issue has been solved and how exactly. Also from the question it is not clear what framework you are using and how does your code behaves differenty from what you expect. You should at least add tags for UI framework